# Why am I obtaining incorrect values for Lipschitz 1/2 norms using the central difference method?

Tags: matlab

The Lipschitz 1/2 norm is defined as the maximum value of the absolute value of the derivative of the function over all points in the domain of the function. I have this code that can approximate this value for a given function:

```
% Define the function f
f = @(x) x.^2;

% Define the domain of the function
x = linspace(-1, 1, 1000);

% Compute the derivative of the function using the central difference method
df = (f(x+1e-8) - f(x-1e-8)) / (2*1e-8);

% Compute the Lipschitz 1/2 norm of the function
lipschitz_norm = max(abs(df));
```

Here, our function `f` and `linspace` for `x` are just an example.

I am trying to compute the norm for `f = @(x) 2*sqrt(1-x), with x = linspace(0, 1, 1000)`. Or really,
`f = @(x) c*sqrt(1-x)`, where `c` is a real number. Theoretically, it's obvious that the norm for any of these functions is `abs(c)`, for a given `c`. Online, using this code with the example `f = @(x) 2*sqrt(1-x)`, with
`x = linspace(0, 1, 1000)` gives `lipschitz_norm = 2`, as it should, but when I run the exact same code on MATLAB on my own, I get `1.4142e+04`. I've tried numerous different examples, and my answers have yet to line up. Is there something going on on my end? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've attached an image of my screen when running the bare code.

Code giving wrong value for norm

[image: 1]

Comment: I get `2` in your example (I'm using R2017b), not `1.4142e+04`. Can you maybe post some code snippet that gives an incorrect result?

Comment: I ran the same code as in the image above on R2017b and got the same 1.4142e+04

Comment: Sorry, I got `2` for your code snippet with `f = @(x) x.^2`. For `f = @(x) 2*sqrt(1-x)` the result is a large value because the derivative tends to `-inf` as `x` tends to `1`. This can be seen with `plot(x, f(x))`, or manually computing the derivative

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about the derivative of the function `f = @(x) c*sqrt(1-x)` is just wrong. The derivative goes to `-Inf` for `x` approaching `1`, therefore `max(abs(df))` should be `Inf`, not `c`.

Matlab is returning the correct value, in the limit of the approximation introduced by the discretization.